# labeling high frequency signal data

Tags: time-series, high-frequency

Was curious if anyone has methodologies they can recommend for systematically labeling (discrete) signals generated from intraday tick data for use in classification or detection models ?

Comment: Hi jharonfe, welcome to Quant.SE! Admittedly, this is not my area of expertise but I think it can be helpful if you can clarify what kind of labelling you're looking for. Could you give some examples?